# Laggy desktop effects Nvidia GT 740 M

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.So far so good,everything seems to go in the right way,except one thing.When i switch to Nvidia,the desktop effects are laggy,i've even got an error,can't remember what was written exactly,something with "nautilus" if i remember.But this lag dissapears when i use Intel HD Graphic.I'm a noob at using Ubuntu,i barely got used with the desktop by now,so a clear and good answer would be greatly appreciated.PS:this problem occured after i updated my Nvidia card(331.113,proprietary,tested).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands and update the nvidia,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Hope this will helps to get relieve from the laggy desktop.